# ESLint sort imports by package name

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I'm trying to sort my imports by package name but it seems like it's not supported based on what is available from the docs.

Is there a way for this to work?

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

The code above fails because it wants *BrowserModule* to be on the first line. But I want this to be considered correct since I want to order by package name.

Here's my ESLint config.

```
"sort-imports": [
            "error",
            {
                "ignoreCase": true,
                "ignoreDeclarationSort": false,
                "ignoreMemberSort": false,
                "memberSyntaxSortOrder": [
                        "none",
                        "all",
                        "multiple",
                        "single"
                ],
                "allowSeparatedGroups": true
            }
        ],
```

Answer (score 11):

I am using [eslint-plugin-import](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-import) and it supports such functionality. Posting my config for reference. It would enforce that React imports are always first, then imports that are starting with `@my_org` and then the rest is configured based on groups' order

```
"import/order": [
      "error",
      {
        "alphabetize": {
          caseInsensitive: true,
          order: "asc",
        },
        "groups": ["external", "builtin", "parent", ["sibling", "index"]],
        "newlines-between": "never",
        "pathGroups": [
          {
            group: "external",
            pattern: "react",
            position: "before",
          },
          {
            group: "external",
            pattern: "@my_org/**",
            position: "after",
          },
        ],
        "pathGroupsExcludedImportTypes": ["builtin"],
      },
    ],
```

Answer (score 2):

The base ESLint rule just doesn't support it - it sorts by name.

You can use a different sorting rule like the one here.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort